# How to calculate the duration using startTime & endTime fields in a QuerySet in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-aggregation

I have this model:

```
class TimeInterval(models.Model):
    startTime = models.DateTimeField()
    endTime = models.DateTimeField()
```

How can I aggregate average time interval using only the QuerySet API?

I tried this:

```
qs = TimeInterval.objects.extra(
    select={"duration": "endTime - startTime"}).aggregate(
        Avg("duration"))
```

but it throws:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'duration' into field. Choices are:
endTime, startTime
```

Comment: Django doesn't support aggregation over fields added with `extra`. The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567543/using-aggregate-on-a-value-introduced-using-extraselect-in-a-django) contain some suggestions for how to work around this limitation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using .aggregate() on a value introduced using .extra(select={…}) in a Django Query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567543/using-aggregate-on-a-value-introduced-using-extraselect-in-a-django)

Comment: @GarethRees, yes is the same question replacing STRFTIME by [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Comment: another work around relies on the fact that `Avg(duration)` equals to `Sum(endTime) - Sum(startTime) / Count` or, almost, `Avg(endTime) - Avg(startTime)`

Answer (score 1):

I'll use a workaround for this.

Create a new field called duration.

Create a pre-save_signal for TimeInterval that would calculate the value for duration.

Then, you can easily use the duration field in your queries.