# Django ORM & hstore : counting unique values of a key

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm, hstore

Having the following model:

```
from django_hstore import hstore
from django.db import models

class Item(VoteModel):
    data = hstore.DictionaryField(db_index=True)
    objects = hstore.HStoreManager()
```

Something like:

```
Item.objects.extra(select={"key": "content_item.data -> 'key'"}).aggregate(Count('key'))
```

doesn't work, cf. [Using .aggregate() on a value introduced using .extra(select={...}) in a Django Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4567543/343834) and https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11671.

The raw SQL which works is the following:

```
SELECT content_item.data -> 'key' AS key, count(*)  FROM content_item GROUP BY key;                                                                               
   key     | count 
-----------+-------
 value1    |   223
 value2    |    28
 value3    |    31
(3 rows)
```

How can I get hte same results through Django's ORM ?

FYI:

```
Item.objects.extra(select={"key": "content_item.data -> 'key'"})
```

translates to:

```
SELECT (content_item.data -> 'key') AS "key", "content_item"."id", "content_item"."data" FROM "content_item"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried with values and order_by?

```
Item.objects.extra(
    select=dict(key = "content_item.data -> 'key'")
).values('key').order_by('key').annotate(total=Count('key'))
```

Something like this works for me in PostgreSQL and Django 1.4.

Comment: Ahaa, clever, thanks a lot ! I knew I could get a list with `values('key')` but also failed trying to use `aggregate` on it. I'll have to spend some more time to fully understand how those orm abstractions work :)

Comment: @MaximeR.: because of the the "admin" app dependency on the ORM I have to swallow it, but IMHO the ORM the weakest component in the Django framework. I dream with someone cloning the Django admin app using Flask, SQLAlchemy and Jinja2.

Comment: @AlexK: for me `django.contrib.admin` is a killer app (not Django itself), I should spare some time and make a clone decoupled from any specific ORM.