# Django ORM Model Property VS Select Extra Which is better

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I am calculating `size` of the item by multiplying two fields.

```
Size = order_size_weight x requested_selling_price
```

I have two approches to do that.

### 1. Model Property

`return float(self.order_size_weight) * float(self.requested_selling_price)`

### 2. Modify QuerySet

```
return self.extra(
                select={"priority": "COALESCE(bm_rank, sales_rank, id)",
        "size": "order_size_weight*requested_selling_price",  # for oder_by size.

})
```

### Problem

When i use the `second` approach, i can not use `Annotate` to aggregate or take sum of all the Sizes.

### Question

1. What is the best / Fast approach to `calculate Size`
2. Can i use Annotate after using `extra select`

### EDIT

### Solution of 2.

I am able to solve the second problem by Using `select extra` before using annotate will help solve the problem.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4567543/821594) is a related question

Comment: I suggest you edit the title to match the question better - now it is quite generic and does not hint of the any facts which might be relevant: COALESCE, select extra, etc..

Comment: did you just down voted for the title? I have updated it though.

Answer (score 0):

While it should still be possible to do both `annotate` and `aggregate` for calculated fields, it's not recommended in terms of database performance if you also want to sort on it (and don't have an index for the calculated result).

For cases like these I would recommend the usage of [enter link description here](http://initcrash.github.io/django-denorm/) (or something similar). You can use a callback function to store the results in the database: http://initcrash.github.io/django-denorm/tutorial.html#creating-denormalized-fields-using-callback-functions

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    order_size_weight = models.IntegerField()
    requested_selling_price = models.IntegerField()

    @denormalized(models.IntegerField)
    def calculate_size(self):
        return float(self.order_size_weight) * float(self.requested_selling_price)
```